# Query Ajax and REST HTTP Basic

Tags: ajax, json

i was reading an article on Query Ajax and REST HTTP Basic and here i got this **http://blog.rassemblr.com/2011/05/jquery-ajax-and-rest-http-basic-authentication-done-deal/**

just see the code

```
$.ajax( {
url : '/model/user.json',
dataType : 'json',
beforeSend : function(xhr) {
var bytes = Crypto.charenc.Binary.stringToBytes(username + ":" + password);
var base64 = Crypto.util.bytesToBase64(bytes);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64);
},
error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
reset();
onError('Invalid username or password. Please try again.');
$('#loginform #user_login').focus();
},
success : function(model) {
cookies();
...
}
});
```

i just do not understand what kind of file type is user.json. please anyone who is familiar with .json file type then please tell me what kind of file type it is. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a file in this case. It is RESTful URL, *.json* part just asks server to return results in JSON format. Probably you can use */model/user.xml* to get response in XML format. Twitter and many other services does this the same way.

Another common way to request specific response format is by providing HTTP Accept header.

For further reading I recommend this resource: http://blog.2partsmagic.com/restful-uri-design

> Some applications return different data if the user adds a different
>   extension. e.g. they may ask for contacts.xml or contacts.json. But
>   different URIs imply different resources. Are the two data formats
>   really two different resources? Or just two different representations
>   of the same resource.

Comment: can u redirect me to any similar kind of sample code or article from where i can get the detail. thanks

Comment: I updated my answer with a link. Code sample heavily depends on server side technology you are using.

Comment: it would very helpful if u include any example where url would look like url : '/model/user.json' or url : '/model/user.xml' thnx

Comment: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/settings.xml and https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/settings.json ?